# Exponential function for synthesizable code

Tags: verilog, xilinx

I'm trying to write a fitness function that is used in a genetic algorithm, and this function contains an exponential part.

How can I implement this function (e^x) where e is the base=2.7 and x is the exponent in the Verilog HDL language as synthesizable code?

Answer (score 5):

In Verilog `**` is the exponential function i.e `e**x`.

You could create a time shared version easily if the exponent is integer, just multiply the base by itself x times, taking x-1 clock cycles.